# agreement: singular or plural verbs with initials

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which verb form is correct in the following?

> F.D.R. stand/stands for “Franklin Delano Roosevelt."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider a set of letters as one singular item, you would need a singular verb:

> 'F.D.R' **stands** for 'Franklin Delano Roosevelt'.
> 'ABC' **begins** the alphabet.

If you consider them as a number of individual letters, then you could use a plural verb:

> The letters 'F.D.R.' **stand** for 'Franklin Delano Roosevelt'.
> The letters 'ABC' **begin** the alphabet.

If they are someone's initials you can call them so explicitly:

> The initials 'F.D.R.' **stand** for 'Franklin Delano Roosevelt'.